# How to Connect dojo/aspect to a Widget?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am having trouble figuring out how to use dojo/aspect with widgets.

Consider the following:

```
require( [ 'dijit/form/Button' ],
function( Button)
{
    var myButton = new Button({label: 'Click me!'});
} );
```

How would I connect to the button's postCreate() or startup() methods to discover when it has been rendered?

There seems to be no point when I can add advice to a method. See the comments, here:

```
require( [ 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/aspect' ],
function( Button, aspect )
{
    // I cannot use aspect.after() here as I have no instance yet
    var myButton = new Button({label: 'Click me!'});
    // ...but I cannot do it here either as the lifecycle has already kicked off
} );
```

(The button is just to make it easier to explain the issue. My real-world problem involves widgets that contain other widgets, so I need to know when the whole lot have rendered before performing an action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By instantiating the widget programmatically, the `postCreate` method of the widget is implicitly being called.  As far as I know there isn't an easy (or really a good reason to) to connect to the `postCreate` stage in the widget lifecycle.

`startup`, on the other hand you need to call explicitly when programmatically instantiating a widget:

```
var myButton = new Button({label: 'Click me!'});
aspect.after(myButton, 'startup', function(){
    console.log('startup called');
});
//place button in page (since startup implies the widget has been placed in the page
myButton.placeAt(someDomNode)
myButton.startup();
```

If you want to do work during the postCreate lifecycle of a widget, you'll likely want to subclass that widget.  Doing so would look something like this:

```
//in a file like my/custom/widget.js
define(['dojo/_base/declare','dijit/form/Button'],function(declare,Button){
  return declare('my.custom.widget',[Button],{
    postCreate:function(){
      //we still want to call the parent class's postCreate function
      this.inherited(arguments);
      //create some other widgets as well
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to connect to the postCreate  stage is that the widget's postCreate method programmatically instantiates its own child widgets there. I needed these child widgets to be completely rendered before performing an action. Anyway, thank you for answering but I think I shall have to create a workaround.

Comment: I edited my answer for a possible way of doing what you want.  There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing, but I think the suggested is the most idiomatic approach for dojo.

Comment: @voidstate do you perform any asynchronous kung-fu inside `create`, `postMixInProperties` or `buildRendering`? Because otherwise your code is synchronous and widgets should be fully created (in memory, not necessarily rendered) right after instantiation.

Comment: In the postCreate method, I do two levels of require() calls, each nested in a loop, ending with adding widgets programmatically to the containerNode. I then needed to show() the whole thing. I solved the problem by using dojo.Deferred.then() for the showing, resolving it when the last require() had loaded.